# php password_verify() fails to identify correct password

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

Password_verify() always fails despite providing the correct raw password. The password_hash() hashed password is stored in mysql in a varchar 256 wide field and when retrieved it is 60 chars. To test things I run this:

Code snippet 1

```
<?php
$done = 0;
while (!$done) {
        echo ("Enter first password: ");
        $first_raw_password =  fgets(STDIN);
        $options = ['cost' => 12, 'salt'=> random_bytes(24)];
        $first_hashed_password = password_hash($first_raw_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
        echo ("\nEnter second password: ");
        $second_raw_password = fgets(STDIN);
        if (password_verify($second_raw_password, $first_hashed_password)) {
                echo ("Password 1 and 2 match!\n");
                $done = 1;
        } else {
                echo ("Password 1 and 2 do not match!\n");
        }
}
```

---

This works.I use output from this snippet (i.e. $first_hashed_password) to paste into a mysql field called pw in a hash table (database: walnuts, table: hash, field: pw).

In my program I retrieve this hashed password to authorize logins as follows:

Code snippet 2

```
`<?php
    session_start();

    //    get stored password for aunthenticated user 
    require "db.inc";
    // upstream, ajaxAuthenticate sends user-entered login info as "value = "password":"entered password"
    if (!($_POST['value'])) {
        echo 'Error: No data posted to login.php';
        return FALSE;
    }

    $response = "";

    //  code here to authenticate entered password
    $str_json = json_decode($_POST['value'], true);

    try {
       $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;charset=utf8mb4", $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failure: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
     $query = "SELECT pw FROM hash";
     $stmt = $pdo->query($query);
     $stmt->execute();
     $dbInfo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     // get hash pw from db into $db_pw
     $db_pw = $dbInfo['pw'];
     // get raw user password
     $user_supplied_password = $str_json["password"];
     // check for match
    if (password_verify($user_supplied_password, $db_pw)) {
       $response = "ok";
    } else {
        $response = "Password incorrect!";
    }
   
    echo ($response);
```

---

Despite entering a password that succeeds in code snippet 1, the correct raw password invariably fails in code snippet 2. I'm flummoxed. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

I expected password_verify() to identify a correct raw password entered and return TRUE. I have tried verifying entered raw password and also that there is enough room in mysql fiekd to accomdate the haashed password.

Comment: How long is the `pw` column in your database? You need it to be at least 60 characters long for current PHP hashes, and 255 is recommended to allow for new hashes in the future.

Comment: You should trim the newline character from the password before hashing it in your first code snippet. trim(fgets(STDIN));

Comment: `hash` only has 1 row in it?

Comment: Thank you Karl Hill!!! That was the problem. Spent many hrs struggling with that! BTW pw col is 256 varchar long, hash table has user and hash cols and submitted data is json encoded, but thx for questions!